# How to make this loop more efficient / faster

Tags: php, for-loop, do-while

I was wondering if there is any way to make this do loop faster ?
I'm not sure if i can replace it with a foreach.

Any help is welcome.

```
        $api = $this->connectToApi();

        $offset = 0;
        $data = [];

        do {
            $response = $api->getPlaylistTracks($playlistId, [
                'offset' => $offset,
            ]);

            $offset += 20;

//            if ($offset > 2000) {
//                die('playlisttoobig');
//            }

            $data = array_merge($data, $response->items);
            $hasNext = $response->next;

        } while ($hasNext);

        return $data;
```

When the `$offset` is around 2000 it still works, but everything above 3000 it just breaks my app.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Is `$api->getPlaylistTracks()` accesses to external api each time?

Comment: Have you considered doing simultaneous HTTP Requests at once, grabbing multiple pages at once, then join them together?

Comment: Yes, it does a request each time

Comment: @KevinY can you elaborate, i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Basically, each getPlaylistTracks would be an HTTP Request, and synchronous, meaning the code after it has to wait for the request to finish before your next iteration of the loop can call getPlaylistTracks again and begin the 2nd HTTP Request to the api you're using. Thus if each page took 3 seconds, and you kept seeing hasNext, for 5 pages, it would take about 15 seconds in total to grab all the results. What I'm saying is, in theory, depending on the api structure, if you started an http request for all 5 pages simultaneous. Then you'd have the complete results in about 3 seconds, maybe 4.